# Visual Studio 2022 is unable to install extensions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

*I want download AsmDude extension for Visual Studio 2022 assembly highlighting.
But it show me an error*

[image: Error_Image]

Logs:

[image: log1]
[image: log2]

How to solve the problem?

Comment: It looks like asmdude is not ready yet: https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/issues/128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension doesn't include compatibility for x64, which visual studio 2022 now is and it doesn't include compatibility for the new major version of visual studio 2022. Each extension ships with an extension manifest in which the author declares which requirements the extension has.

Once the extension is updated by the author it should become installable.

For now you'll need to stick to visual studio 2019.

Comment: AsmDude2 with support for VS2022 has just been released!